# Remove html label tag text when value is entered - with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i'm trying to remove the label and its value from my input html tag whenever the person enters a value, and the code that I have right now does the job but it only removes the value when I click on the input box. Once I enter a value the label is stuck there along with the value of the input. Can someone help me make it so the label is removed completely not just when it's clicked on. And is this something I can do with css? if I can't then how would I do it with javascript?

```css
.text-input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.text-input-wrapper label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.text-input-wrapper label::before {
  transition: 0s;
}

.text-input-wrapper label.icon1::before {
  content: 'Email';
}

.text-input-wrapper label.icon2::before {
  content: 'Password';
}

.text-input-wrapper input {
  padding: 0 2rem 0;
}

.text-input-wrapper input:focus+label::before,
.text-input-wrapper input:active+label::before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="clearfix credentials-form login-form" method="POST">

  <div class="credentials-form__fields">

    <div class="text-input standard login-text-input login-email">

      <div class="text-input-error-wrapper">
      </div>

      <div class="text-input-wrapper">

        <input type="email" id="login_email2812380460348143" class="text-input-input" name="login_email" value="" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" inputmode="text">

        <label for="login_email2812380460348143" class="icon1"></label>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div>

      <div class="tooltip-container">
      </div>

      <div class="text-input standard login-text-input login-password">

        <div class="text-input-error-wrapper">
        </div>

        <div class="text-input-wrapper">

          <input type="password" id="login_password5101720956289264" class="text-input-input password-input" name="login_password" value="" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" inputmode="text">
          <label for="login_password5101720956289264" class="icon2"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="login-button signin-button button-primary" type="submit">
    
                            <div class="signin-text">Sign in
                            </div></button>
</form>
```

Comment: "*[I'm] trying to remove the label and its value from my input html tag*" - please don't, for accessibility (and user-experience) reasons, the label should remain visible to the user at all times.

Comment: the label text is inside the input. i want to remove it when a person is entering their details

Comment: @ruzter instead of removing the label ...jus display it above the input when user enter the details

Comment: @ruzter try to look at how to grow and shrink label based on input data

Comment: yes i understand what you guys are saying but the design of my page won't let me do that, that's why i need a way to get the label removed when a value is entered.

Comment: I mean, it sounds like a job for the [placeholder attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) since it's exactly a scenario it was made for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way...

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.text-input-wrapper input');
const labels = document.querySelectorAll('.text-input-wrapper label');

inputs.forEach((input, i) => {
   input.addEventListener('input', () => {
      labels[i].style.opacity = 0;
   });
});
```

Comment: Got a typo in your example, it will also get pretty noisy firing every time the value changes.

Comment: @ChrisW. Oops you're right. fixing now. Maybe a `focus` event is less noisy but the OP want to hide the label only when some value is entered...

Answer (score 0):

Use an `onInput` event instead of an `onChange` one.